# In Google Spreadsheets' bubble graph, how do I set to bubble size to the frequency of the items?

Tags: google-sheets, bubble-chart

I have this table:

```
money  love
1      7
2      8
2      8
5      3
8      5
```

On a buuble graph, how do I set the bubble size to the frequency of recurring value sets? Meaning, the money:2, love:8 bubble will be of size 2, while the other 3 bubbles' size will be 1?

Answer (score 4):

In addition, once you have calculated the frequencies as explained in the other answers, if you want to have more control over the relative size of the bubbles, check out the answer to this question:

[How can you control the relative bubble size in a Google Sheets Bubble Chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78122271/how-can-you-control-the-relative-bubble-size-in-a-google-sheets-bubble-chart/78122272#78122272)

Comment: I don't think this was what the OP was looking for but thank you so much for figuring out Google's ridiculous bubble scaling methodology. You should consider asking a new question about how to set bubble scaling and adding your answer so it is easier to find for people trying to figure this out.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this, but I've now asked the question separately, then changed the answer here to be a link to my answer on that question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to get the counts:

```
=filter(countifs(A2:A,A2:A,B2:B,B2:B),A2:A<>"")
```

but unfortunately the actual bubble size seems disproportionate:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If money and love are in Col A and Col B respectively then you can get frequency in Col C by using this formula in C2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A6&"?"&B2:B6), QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A6&"?"&B2:B6), "select Col1, count(Col1) group by Col1" , 0), 2, 0))
```

That can then be used as an input to size in the bubble chart.